# Copy bits from a variable to another one, with bits swapped with LUT

Tags: c

In C language, I want to fill two 8-bit variables "a" and "b" with bits coming from a 16-bit variable "c".
The bits in the 16 bits variable are shuffled without any logical order, which can be for example :

a.4 | b.2 | b.6 | b.0 | a.0 | a.7 | a.6 | b.1 | b.2 | b.7 | b.4 | a.5 | a.1 | a.2 | b.3 | b.5

Is there a way to do that?
The goal is to have a quite lisible look-up table.

Comment: Your explanation isn't clear: `a.4` does that mean bit 4 in both `a` and `c`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It means bit 4 of `a`.  The entire sequence of 16 bits is `c`.  So the `a.4`  entry indicates that bit 15 of `c` is bit 4 of `a`.  The `b.2` entry indicates that bit 14 of `c` is bit 2 of `b`, etc.

Comment: Where does th shuffling mapping come from? How is it defined? We need some more information.

Comment: @TomKarzes that's it. The software is running on an embedded system, the mapping comes from a physical wiring.

Comment: @fdamien12 The easiest way to do this is to initialize `a` and `b` to zero, then loop over the bits in `c`.  For each new bit, extract it, then shift it into its final position and bitwise-OR it into either `a` or `b`, depending on the designated destination.

Comment: This can probably done in a few magic instructions with SSE or BMI instructions - what's the target processor?

Comment: One or two intervening LUTs would only increase the complexity and opportunity for a problem (bug). For maintainability, this "shuffling" of individual bits wants to be clearly specified in code. Example: your sample assignments lists `b.2` twice, and is missing `a.3`... Try coding it, bit by bit, and come back to us if you have difficulties.

Answer (score -1):

This code randomizes and shuffles bits in c after copying initial, you stated it is intended to be used in a embedded system but you didn't provide any information about which embedded system it is, it could be an arduino, it could be a obscure system from 80s, it could be a diy pcb with a random stm32 attached to it, we can't know :)

```
// Code is under public domain, use it like what you want
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    uint16_t initial = 4040; /* 24 will be shuffled */
    uint16_t c = 0;
    
    
    /* shuffle bits */
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(uint16_t) * 8; ++i) {
        c ^= initial & (1 << (rand() % 16));
    }
    
    uint8_t a = 0;
    uint8_t b = 0;



    a = ((unsigned char*)&c)[0];
    b = ((unsigned char*)&c)[1];
    
    for(unsigned char i = 0; i < sizeof(uint16_t) * 8; ++i) {
        printf("%c.%d = %d | ", ('a' * ((i < 8))) + ('b' * ((i >= 8))), ((i + 1) * (i < 8)) + ((i + 1 - 8) * (i >= 8)), ((a >> i)) & 1);
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

This code will print this (obviously yours going to be random):

a.1 = 1 | a.2 = 0 | a.3 = 1 | a.4 = 1 | a.5 = 0 | a.6 = 1 | a.7 = 1 | a.8 = 1 | b.1 = 0 | b.2 = 0 | b.3 = 0 | b.4 = 1 | b.5 = 0 | b.6 = 1 | b.7 = 0 | b.8 = 0 |